# How to get format from multiple NamedItems in Excel with Office.js?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I'm trying to retrieve some formatting info from a list of NamedItems. Basically, my spreadsheet has a few named ranges spread across multiple worksheets and I want to get some formatting information like font size for each of these named ranges.

This is what I have so far:

```
async function getRangesAndJson() {
  // 1. Find all prz ranges in file
  let myRanges = await Excel.run(async ctx => {
    const namedRangesInFile = ctx.workbook.names;
    namedRangesInFile.load("items");
    await ctx.sync();
    return namedRangesInFile.items.filter(range => range.name.startsWith("abc_"));
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
      console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
  });

  // 2. Extract their formatting in JSON, one by one
  await Excel.run(async function(ctx) {
    for (let index = 0; index < myRanges.length; index++) {
      const namedRange = myRanges[index];
      const range = namedRange.getRange();
    }
    await ctx.sync();
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log("error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
      console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
  });
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this, especially since this operation requires looping a lot.
What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you get the ranges from each named Item, you could use range.format.font to get the font from this range if the font of this range is same.

```
  const range = namedRange.getRange();
  range.load(["format/*", "format/fill", "format/borders", "format/font"]);
  await ctx.sync();
  console.log(range.format.font.name);
```

if you want to getfont name for each individual cell in this range, you may need to use `range.getCellProperties`, please refers to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=excel-js-preview#getcellproperties-cellpropertiesloadoptions-)

BTW, from [perf consideration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern), we suggest not put context.sync in a loop.

Comment: thanks for the input, unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue. Would calling await Excel.run(...) inside a for loop be any better ?

Comment: From my understanding of your question description, I thought the issue is to get the formatting (font size) of the ranges in each namedItem.  so do you mean my sample code cannot get the font size of the ranges?